# Accessing a Remote Database with VB6

Tags: database, ms-access, vb6, odbc

How to access a remote database with Visual Basic 6?

It's been a while since I've done any code in Visual Basic 6, I remember ODBC connections however I'm not sure how I would go about it. All that I need is to have a database on a host computer and then some clients would connect to it, probably without need to guarantee simultaneous access.

Edit: I'm trying to access a Microsoft Access database.

Comment: What type of database are you trying to access?

Comment: What do you mean by "remote?"  Across a LAN?  Across the public Internet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use ADODB, here is a [tutorial](http://www.vb6.us/tutorials/database-access-ado-vb6-tutorial) that covers most of what you need.

Answer (score 1):

[This tutorial](http://www.timesheetsmts.com/adotutorial.htm) should help you get started.

Answer (score 0):

The methods mentioned by @rick_schott and @eric_j are good and legit, but if you want speed, that is not the way to go.

Instead, you want to use DAO and Jet (the technology released prior to ADODB).  Here is a pretty good tutorial:

http://www.vb6.us/tutorials/using-dao-data-access-objects-code-tutorial